# Julia: Warning: Some registries failed to update: — registry detached

Tags: github, julia, github-actions

I am trying to use the TagBot on GitHub

The automerge does not work, it fails after a warning:

[ Info: Attempting to import the package
Copying registry from ~/work/General/General
Added registry General to /tmp/jl_YVIDjr/registries/General
[ Info: Attempting to Pkg.add package...
Updating registry at /tmp/jl_YVIDjr/registries/General
┌ Warning: Some registries failed to update:
│ — /tmp/jl_YVIDjr/registries/General — registry detached
└ @ Pkg.Types /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1220

I removed the general registry, even reinstalled julia from scratch but it does not resolve the problem.
please advice me.